# Insert path to class in composer, so I can remove it in "use" in php

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

In this case I have multiple footer classes. Now I have to edit the "Moduler" file to switch footers. Is it possible to declare the version of the footer in composer and change the "use" path to something more static like:

```
use Modules\Footer;
```

And specify the version of the footer in composer like:

```
App\\Helpers\\Moduler\\Modules\\Views\\Footer\\Footer__2\\Footer
```

This is the code I'm using right now

```
<?php namespace App\Helpers\Moduler;

use App\Helpers\Moduler\Modules\Views\Footer\Footer__2\Footer;

class Moduler
{
    use Footer;

    public function footer()
    {
        return $this->call_footer();
    }

    public static function instance()
    {
        return new Moduler();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand your problem. But it seems like something which should be very simple to solve and u just over engineered it so u can use `use` and composer and everything else possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [class aliases](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) for this:

```
class_alias('App\Helpers\Moduler\Modules\Views\\ooter\Footer__2\Footer', 'Modules\Footer');
```

You can put this in some file and include it automatically using [`files`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) setting in `composer.json`.

But honestly, it looks like really ugly magic and you (or someone else which will need to deal with that in future) will regret that. Use separate helper class and/or dependency injection instead - it will be more clear and predictable than magic traits driven by aliases.

Comment: Thanks You, I'll look forward other options